# vdriveusa Timer Bypass

Tags: javascript, html

So I have looked everywhere and I would like to know if it is possible to disable a timer.

They have a next button but you can't click it until a certain time.

If anyone can help me bypass that would be great, it is a very long driver course and I honestly don't have the time for it, because I am on vacation.

Here is the source script for the button:

```
</span></div><div class="buttons"><div class="singlebutton"><form method="get" action="http://www.vdriveusa.com/moodle/mod/flash/view.php"><div><input type="submit" value="Back" /><input type="hidden" name="id" value="357960" /><input type="hidden" name="vid" value="142742" /><input type="hidden" name="sesskey" value="..." /></div></form></div><div class="singlebutton"><form method="get" action="http://www.vdriveusa.com/moodle/mod/flash/view.php"><div><input type="submit" value="Next" /><input type="hidden" name="id" value="357960" /><input type="hidden" name="vid" value="142748" /><input type="hidden" name="sesskey" value="..." /></div></form></div></div>  


<script>setTimeout('myfunction()',28000);</script>
    <script>
            var body='';
            body.onload=disabeinput();

            function myfunction(){
                var allinputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
                for(i=0;i<allinputs.length;i++){
                    if(allinputs[i].value=='Next'){
                        allinputs[i].disabled=false;
                    }
                 }
             }
             function disabeinput(){
                var allinputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
                for(i=0;i<allinputs.length;i++){
                    if(allinputs[i].value=='Next'){
                        allinputs[i].disabled=true;
                    }
                }
             }
    </script>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: myVar = setTimeout("javascript function", milliseconds);

Comment: What would be the javascript function?

Answer (score 0):

plz check this.I am not sure you meant this

```
</span></div><div class="buttons"><div class="singlebutton"><form method="get" action="http://www.vdriveusa.com/moodle/mod/flash/view.php"><div><input type="submit" value="Back" /><input type="hidden" name="id" value="357960" /><input type="hidden" name="vid" value="142742" /><input type="hidden" name="sesskey" value="..." /></div></form></div><div class="singlebutton"><form method="get" action="/ok"><div><input type="submit" value="Next" /><input type="hidden" name="id" value="357960" /><input type="hidden" name="vid" value="142748" /><input type="hidden" name="sesskey" value="..." /></div></form></div></div>  



    <script>
            var body='';
            body.onload=disabeinput();

            function myfunction(){
                var allinputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
                for(i=0;i<allinputs.length;i++){
                    if(allinputs[i].value=='Next'){
                        allinputs[i].disabled=false;
                    }
                 }
             }
             function disabeinput(){
                var allinputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
                for(i=0;i<allinputs.length;i++){
                    if(allinputs[i].value=='Next'){
                        allinputs[i].disabled=true;
                    }
                }
                setTimeout(myfunction,3000);
             }
    </script>
```

Here is the jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/c6hbL6rx/1/

Comment: view-source:http://www.vdriveusa.com/moodle/mod/flash/view.php?id=357963&vid=122222

Comment: asking for login credentials